# SVG text fill not filling with a specified color

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a an SVG of text and a mask (animating the mask later on) that I'd initially like to have a fill of white. However, when I set the fill to white, the text goes missing as if the color is transparent instead. Here is the relevant code...

```css
svg {
  margin: 0;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

rect {
  -webkit-mask: url(#mask);
  mask: url(#mask);
  fill: #f00;
}

defs {
  mask {
    text {
      font-size: 8vw;
      /* Using black to illustrate text fill isn't updating */
      fill: #000;
    }
  }
}

#editText {
  @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    transform: translateY(-10%);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
      <text x="50%" y="50vh" text-anchor="middle">
        Text line 1
      </text>
      <text
        id="editText"
        x="50%"
        y="65vh"
        text-anchor="middle"
      >
        Text line 2
      </text>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
</svg>
```

Here is how it looks locally...
[image: How it currently looks]

Here is how it should look (with white text instead of being transparent)

[image: how it should look]

I've tried a combination of strokes, colors and gradients on the text element with no luck. Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: because it's used as mask so you cannot change its color, it need to remain transparent so you can see through it. What is behind need to have a whie color. Same logic for your rect element

Comment: Okay, is there any way of setting an initial color on the text to animate from white to transparent? For context, the transparency is so the user can see the layer underneath the red one if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to use the mask to *cut* the rectangle with the shape of the text so that you can see what is below that cutout. If that is the case, the main issue I see is with the `css` selectors. You have one selector for all `rect` elements in the page, which includes the element of the mask. I think you need to make sure that you are affecting only the elements you want to affect. For instance, you can use `id` and `class` selectors:

```css
svg {
  margin: 0;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#background{
  fill: #ff0;
}

#outrect {
  -webkit-mask: url(#mask);
  mask: url(#mask);
  fill: #f00;
}

.masktext{
  stroke: #000;
}
#maskrect{
  fill: #fff;
}

#editText {
  @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    transform: translateY(-10%);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
      <rect id="maskrect" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
      <text class="masktext" x="50%" y="50vh" text-anchor="middle">
        Text line 1
      </text>
      <text
        id="editText"
        class="masktext"
        x="50%"
        y="65vh"
        text-anchor="middle"
      >
        Text line 2
      </text>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect id="background" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
  <rect id="outrect" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
</svg>
```

I also added a yellow rectangle *below* to see that transparency. Now you can modulate the transparency by changing the color of `.masktext` and `#maskrect`.